# How to Write the data into Google MemoryStore(Redis) using Apache Beam with DataFlowRunner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-memorystore

I am trying to read the data from Google MemoryStore and transforming the data and writing back to MemoryStore using RedisIO API.
I am able to read the data but unable to write back to MemoryStore.
When I am trying local Redis server with Dataflow DirectRunner it is working.
When I am trying Google MemoryStore with DirectRunner it is working.
But with DataFlowRunner and MemoryStore it is not working.(program exited with 0 status).
MemoryStore and DataFlow jobs are running within same zone(us-central1-a).

Here is the code that I  am using:

```
package com.example;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.redis.RedisIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.SimpleFunction;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.KV;




public class RedisReadRedisWrite {

/** A SimpleFunction that converts a Word and Count into a printable string. */
public static class FormatAsTextFn extends SimpleFunction<KV<String, String>, KV<String, String>> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public KV<String, String> apply(KV<String, String> input) {
        System.out.println("Original: " + input.getKey() + " " + input.getValue());
        System.out.println("Modified: " + "X_" + input.getKey() + "X_" + input.getValue());
        return KV.of("X_" + input.getKey(), "X_" + input.getValue().substring(3));
    }
}

public interface WordCountOptions extends PipelineOptions {

}

static void runWordCount(WordCountOptions options) {
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

    p.apply(RedisIO.read().withEndpoint("10.0.0.12", 6379).withKeyPattern("FOO*"))
            .apply(MapElements.via(new FormatAsTextFn())).apply(RedisIO.write().withEndpoint("10.0.0.12", 6379));

    p.run().waitUntilFinish();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    WordCountOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(WordCountOptions.class);

    runWordCount(options);
}
}
```

Comment: Could you add some more info to your question? I.e. a snippet of your code, full logs or something else. At first sight the only thing I can think of is some permissions not being added, but without more info I cannot conclude anything.